# Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 Can't Open cshtml Files

Tags: razor

I just did the updates that the notification bar told me about. It included Update 1 and I quickly saw something called micro-update during the install. Not sure what that was.

Now whenever I try to open a cshtml file I get an dreaded "Object reference not set to the instance of an object".

I try running devenv with logging, but didn't see any errors in the log.

I tried a complete repair and that didn't fix it.

What do I do now? I don't see the update 1 in add-remove programs, so I can't uninstall it.

The weird thing is I have been running on Update 1 for a week or 2 now. I am not sure why there was another update 1.

Please help...

Answer (score -1):

Look at this thread (https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/276).
I'm uninstalling ASP.NET 5 1 RC1 update to see if it works

Comment: Don't just tell users to look at the thread. Pull snippets from the thread and explain.